# Why is it better to split a delete OR query into 2 individual queries?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

In a PostgreSQL 14.5 table that gets quite large we have 2 columns for which we would need to search by in order to delete data. Originally we implemented the cleanup in one single SQL query with an OR. Sample cleanup query for ID 1:

```
delete from task_dependency where task_id = 1 or depends_on_task_id = 1;
```

There were no individual indexes on those columns, only a unique index containing both. At this point we get this execution plan for the delete query (Cost between 0 and 1'241'500):
[image: Execution plan before creating indexes]

To improve that, individual indexes on the tables were created:

```
CREATE INDEX task_dependency_task_id_idx ON task_dependency (task_id);
CREATE INDEX task_dependency_depends_on_task_id_idx ON task_dependency (depends_on_task_id);
```

After that, the query execution plan improved (Cost between 32 and 5'316):
[image: Execution plan after creating the indexes]

It's a good improvement, but I was wondering why 2 Bitmap Index Scans instead of 2 Index Scans?

If we break the query into 2 queries, the cost gets better (Cost between 1 and 672):

```
delete from task_dependency where task_id = 1;
delete from task_dependency where depends_on_task_id = 1;
```

[image: Execution plan after creating indexes, first query]
[image: Execution plan after creating indexes, second query]

My question is why the DB can't figure out for this OR to make 2 Index Scan itself?
Is there anything that could be changed to avoid this or is it always better to execute 2 `delete` queries instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your table is highly clustered on the task_id column.  This is why the cost is so low for updating 1194 tuples, because it expects to find all of them in a small number of pages.

This type of clustering information is not made use of (or at least no effectively) when planning Bitmap scans.

Comment: It's true that the entries with the same task_id are inserted together. Not as the ones with the same depends_on_task_id. So this explanation makes sense. So my learning is: it's not a general rule that 2 delete queries are better than one with an OR, but it is for this specific scenario.

Comment: Correct, it is not a general rule, just specific to this situation.  But note that the bitmap should not actually be slow, it is just estimated wrong.